# Anybody knows how to implement okhttp oauth token refreshes based on article?

Tags: kotlin, oauth, retrofit, okhttp, coinbase-api

im trying to implement what said in this article:
https://blog.coinbase.com/okhttp-oauth-token-refreshes-b598f55dd3b2

im working on an android app using kotlin
for a coibase wallet.

I was able to get the authorization code, and then an authorization token with retrofit. i have used the token to get user information and also refresh a token. But when it came to create address i am getting wrong token response even if im using a newly created token by using the refresh token with the correct scope create wallet address
so as a suggestion , mentor on my course asked me to use that article implementation,  so that tokens are refreshed automatically with correct headers and all.

so i can't find a way to implement correctly and cant find an example that uses code from the article.

ill share my code tomorrow, hope someone can help with this. Thank you for your time, i appreciate.

This is the code im trying to implement based on the article:

```
object UserNetwork {
//private val logger = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
 //   .setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY )
private val accessTokenProvider = AccessTokenProviderImp()
private val accessTokenInterceptor = AccessTokenInterceptor(accessTokenProvider)
val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .addNetworkInterceptor(accessTokenInterceptor)
    .authenticator(AccessTokenAuthenticator(accessTokenProvider))
    .build()
val coinBaseClienApiCalls:CoinBaseClienApiCalls
    get(){
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://api.coinbase.com/")
            .client(client)
            .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
            .create(CoinBaseClienApiCalls::class.java)
    }

private class UserCallBack(
    private val onSuccess:(UserData.Data) -> Unit): Callback<UserData> {
    override fun onResponse(call: Call<UserData>, response: Response<UserData>) {
        Log.e("ON Response User:"," ${response.body()?.data?.name}")
        val newClient = UserData.Data(
            name = response.body()?.data?.name?:"",
            avatarUrl = response.body()?.data?.avatarUrl?:"",
            id = response.body()?.data?.id?:"",
            profileBio = response.body()?.data?.profileBio?:"",
            profileLocation = response.body()?.data?.profileLocation?:"",
            profileUrl = response.body()?.data?.profileUrl ?:"",
            resource = response.body()?.data?.resource?:"",
            resourcePath = response.body()?.data?.resourcePath?:"",
            username = response.body()?.data?.username?:""
        )
        Log.e("RESPONDED WITH:","Client: ${newClient.name},${newClient.id} ${response.isSuccessful}")
        onSuccess(newClient)
    }

    override fun onFailure(call: Call<UserData>, t: Throwable) {
        Log.e("On Failure Address:","$t")
    }
}

fun getUser (onSuccess: (UserData.Data) -> Unit){
    var token = if(Repository.accessToken != ""){
        Repository.accessToken

    }else{
        ""
    }
    if(token != ""){

        coinBaseClienApiCalls.getUser("Bearer $token").enqueue(UserCallBack(onSuccess)) //getUser(token).enqueue(AddressCallBack(onSuccess))
    }else{
        Log.e("ACCESS TOKEN IN REPOSITORY","${Repository.accessToken}")
    }

}
```

}

```
class AccessTokenInterceptor(
private val tokenProvider: AccessTokenProvider
```

) : Interceptor {

```
override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
    val token = tokenProvider.token()

    return if (token == null) {
        chain.proceed(chain.request())
    } else {
        val authenticatedRequest = chain.request()
            .newBuilder()
            .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer $token")
            .build()
        chain.proceed(authenticatedRequest)
    }
}
```

}

interface AccessTokenProvider {

```
/**
 * Returns an access token. In the event that you don't have a token return null.
 */
fun token(): String?

/**
 * Refreshes the token and returns it. This call should be made synchronously.
 * In the event that the token could not be refreshed return null.
 */
fun refreshToken(): String?
```

}

```
class AccessTokenAuthenticator(
private val tokenProvider: AccessTokenProvider
```

) : Authenticator {

```
override fun authenticate(route: Route?, response: Response): Request? {
    // We need to have a token in order to refresh it.
    val token = tokenProvider.token() ?: return null

    synchronized(this) {
        val newToken = tokenProvider.token()
        Log.e("NEW TOKEN AUTHENTICATOR","$newToken")

        // Check if the request made was previously made as an authenticated request.
        if (response.request.header("Authorization") != null) {

            // If the token has changed since the request was made, use the new token.
            if (newToken != token) {
                Log.e("Testing Authenticator1","Testing1")

                return response.request
                    .newBuilder()
                    .removeHeader("Authorization")
                    .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer $newToken")
                    .build()
            }

            val updatedToken = tokenProvider.refreshToken() ?: return null
            Log.e("Testing Authenticator2","Testing2")

            // Retry the request with the new token.
            return response.request
                .newBuilder()
                .removeHeader("Authorization")
                .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer $updatedToken")
                .build()

        }
    }
    return null
}
```

}

```
class AccessTokenProviderImp():AccessTokenProvider {
var token = Repository.accessToken
override fun token(): String? {
    return token
}

override fun refreshToken(): String? {
    return token
}
```

}

Comment: It's hard to answer until you post your sample code tomorrow.

Comment: Added code to the original question, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the way the AccessTokenProviderImp() requested the existing token or the newly refreshed token, remove the check if (newToken != token) from Authenticator. Works great.